# IntelliJ IDEA is not recognizing my java files as runnable and instead wants to run the class files. Any ideas of how to fix?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Anytime I try to run a java file by clicking run, it instead tries to run the class file and thus gives a no main method error.

When I try to right click on a java file and run that, it doesn't recogize it as a file that is runable.

I am still able to run programs from the command prompt but I would prefer to be able to run them in IntelliJ.

This occurred after trying to create a Class path when using JSon Libraries.

Edit:

Normally it shows java files with this icon: 
[image]

But instead it's showing this icon for java files: [image]

I think the change in icon might have something to do with it.

Edit 2: 
the exact error I get is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java.exe"...bunch of other program file locations

Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Consider posting`mvce` https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do your Java classes *have* a main method?  You can't run Java programs without one...

Comment: A class file is just a compiled Java source file, so if the latter has a `main` method, then the former should have one too.  Did you configure an SDK in IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes my java classes do have a main method. I've also tried running previous projects that would run in the past.

Comment: Yes I have an SDK configured in IntelliJ. I was able to run projects in it just yesterday. I'm trying to figure out why it suddenly stopped allowing me to.

Comment: As loath as I am to ask this, maybe you could show us a picture of what you're seeing in your IDE when you try to run the application.

Comment: I edited the question to show the icon change compared to normal.

Comment: I would strongly suggest to use Maven or Gradle for your project. IntelliJ understands those and will setup your project correctly. It will also make it easier for others to get started with your project.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I had the same problem and found out that my src wasn't marked as Sources Root. To change this:

- right-mouse click on your src
- navigate to "Mark Directory As"
- choose "Sources Root"
  It will now recognize your files correctly and your main classes will be able to run again

IntelliJ not recognizing my .java-files:
[image]

Problem solved:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem.It wouldn't pick up ModlServer in any project. 
(Not just limited to the one I had open).

I had to file -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings

---

[image]

**Note:** I lost all my live templates, fonts, etc so just a heads up.

Answer (score 2):

I restarted my computer and that somehow fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

My issue was that I have multiple modules for my project and the module I was working on (where java files were not recognized) was not included in the main pom. I just added that module in the main (project) pom and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this at `Intelij2023` by using `JDK17` as the JDK the IDE uses to **import** java source files.

Mind this JDK version does not need to be the same you use to build your project.

1. Go to: `Settings > Build, Executio, Deployment> Build Tools > Maven > Importer`
2. Set the `JDK For Importer` to zulu-17

I'm using zulu-17 as JDK for imports and coretto-8 to build the project (having JDK version 8 seems to be preventing intelij to properly recognize the project structure)

Comment: I meant intelij version 2022.3.2

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding `String[] args` to the parameter list of my main method.

It now looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and click 'Add framework support' all directories and classes should now be the right type.

Answer (score 0):

As @HermanTheGerman said: The easiest solution is to double-check your main method to make sure that it includes correct spelling of keywords and types and that it includes your square brackets after `"String"`, and afterwards to  RECOMPILE THE CLASS if the Run button does not "green" up.

```
public class W3Question8 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    }
}
```

After this, you might still need to edit the configuration under the `"Run"` tab and point your IDE to the location of the class. The class should pop up alone in the search menu that pops up, if not then click `"project"` on the same window and pick your class. Done.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Maven or Gradle, try to re-import the project and see if that helps. Could be that your IDEA project has some incorrect settings in it set by mistake, so this way those would be removed.

Comment: I'm not using maven or gradle. I've tried re-importing projects as well as importing projects that have worked in the past.