# Can't run JavaFX in Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I create a JavaFx project using IntelliJ following the doc: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/, but the sample file HelloApplication.java (along with other files) is not runnable no matter what I tried. Dont know what should I do about it [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obbem.jpg)

I watched some tutorial videos about JavaFx set up but nobody encouter the same situation like me, at least all their sample code can run

Comment: I would guess that IntelliJ has gotten confused, which happens sometimes. First, quit and restart IntelliJ. And upgrade to the latest version of IntelliJ. If problem persists, do a Maven `clean` & `install`. If problem persists, clear the caches in IntelliJ. Be sure to install & activate the JavaFX plugin for IntelliJ. Edit your Question to report the result of each of these steps.

Comment: By the way, IntelliJ is able to create a new JavaFX project for you. See [the manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).

Comment: See also, [*This file in the editor in not runnable intelliJ idea using java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75636364/642706) and [*IntelliJ IDEA is not recognizing my java files as runnable and instead wants to run the class files. Any ideas of how to fix?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53211436/642706)

Comment: Yup. From the IDE perspective, the issue is that the folder with your production code is not marked as a sources root. So you need to do it either manually (right-click -> Mark Dir. As -> Sources Root [blue icon]) or by using a correct pom.xml configuration, which is something best left for IDE project creation wizard to deal with.

Comment: It might help to post you `pom.xml` file (and possibly other configuration files). This looks like the standard IntelliJ JavaFX project from the project generator. How did you create this project?

Comment: @James_D I don't see a Gradle or Maven icon over at the far right of the screenshot, under the notification bell icon.  So the answer probably is, "Create the project from the Intellij wizard using a build engine".

Comment: @DaveB Yes, kind of why I was asking for clarification. The OP says they followed the instructions at openjfx.io; there's a pom.xml and a module-info.java, which suggest a modular project with Maven, however those instructions use the javafx.maven-archetype which generates a different set of sample files (at least when I try it).